# Hang-indent a list without affecting left margin

Tags: html, css

How can you hang-indent a list so that the left margin remains unchanged, and the indented lines are indented to the right.

Kindly see the example below:

```css
.custom-list {
    padding-left: 16px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    /*text-indent: -22px ;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li class="custom-list">I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I
                am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of
                text.
            </li>

            <li class="custom-list">I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I
                am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of text. I am a long piece of
                text.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compensate for `text-indent` adjustment by using the `margin-left` property

```
li {
    text-indent: -4em;
    margin-left: 6em;
}
```